# Cool clock question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

A clock has a second, minute, and hour hand. A fly initially rides on the second hand
of the clock starting at noon. Every time the hand the fly is currently riding crosses
with another, the fly will then switch to riding the other hand. Once the clock strikes
midnight, how many revolutions has the fly taken?

Comment: Imagine that there is not just one but three flies, one on each hand of the clock and switching when one hand crosses the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed a cool clock question, thanks for posting! I will elaborate my comment into a full answer.

Imagine that there is not just one but three flies, one on each hand. Every time two of the hands cross, the flies on them switch hands. They are racing to see which one makes more revolutions.

The flies never change positions. In other words, the one that began on the third (hours) hand will always be in last place, the one that began on the first (seconds) hand will always be in first place and the difference in the angle traveled between them will always be at most one revolution.
So when the three flies will reach midnight there will be a difference of at most one revolution between the first and the last.

Let $x \le y \le z \le x+1$ be the number of revolutions of the last, middle and first flies, respectively. Then $x+y+z$ equals the number of revolutions of the three hands of the clock combined, which is $1+12+720 = 733$. Let $y = x+\epsilon,\ z = y+\delta$ for $\epsilon, \delta \in \{0, 1\}.$ Reducing the equation $$x+y+z=733$$ modulo $3$ gives
$$2\epsilon+\delta \equiv 1\ (\text{mod } 3),$$ whose only solution is $\epsilon = 0, \delta = 1.$ Plugging into the previous equation, $$3x+1=733,$$ and $$\begin{align*}x &= 244 && \\ y &= 244 &&\text{(this was the requested value)} \\ z &= 245. && \end{align*}$$
We also obtain that the fly that began on the minutes hand will die on the hours hand (and vice versa).